# How to properly format data for tf-RNN model

Tags: tensorflow

I took inspiration from [here](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/tensorflow-rnn-api-2bb31821b185#.u3wew5ck0) and [here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/lstm-by-example-using-tensorflow-feb0c1968537) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFARw8Pm0Gk), but since both examples have single values as input, or split up the input vector, I don't see how I properly adjust the model to my data.
Every x has a format of (1,62) and I would like the model to "look back" 3 steps.
This model is somehow working:
**variables**

```
batch_size = 256
n_input = 62
chunk_size = 31
n_chunks = 2
```

**batches**

```
for i in range(total_batch-1):
  batch_x = X_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
  batch_y = Y_train[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
  batch_x = batch_x.reshape([batch_size, n_chunks, chunk_size])
  batch_y = np.transpose([batch_y])
  _, c, p = sess.run([optimizer, perc_err, prediction], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                      y: batch_y})
```

**model**

```
def recurrent_neural_network(x, args):
    layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input*3,1])),
                        'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}
    x = tf.transpose(x, [1,0,2])
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, chunk_size])
    x = tf.split(x, n_chunks, 0)
    cells = []
    for _ in xrange(args.num_layers):
        cell = rnn.NASCell(n_input*3)
        cells.append(cell)
    rnn_cells = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
    outputs , states = tf.contrib.rnn.static_rnn(rnn_cells, x, dtype = tf.float32)
    output = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], layer['weights']) + layer['biases']
    return output
```

So, doesn't this split every input into 2 chunks and the model "sees" only the last one. (the tensor gets split into 2 chunks of shapes (?,31)). How can I adjust the matrices so it feeds in 3 values of size 62 - or is this a stupid idea? :)
thx

Comment: Do you have the full code as a gist, runnable in one step? BTW, Erik's blog is a great find!

Comment: @ruohoruotsi Thanks for responding - I found a solution: I'm adding old elements and chopping it up again (as described above).. quite ugly but it works. here is the full file: https://github.com/derdav3/tf-sparql/blob/master/graph_vec_nn/rnn.py